# how to prove $\nabla_AtrABA^T=AB+AB^T$

Tags: intuition, matrix-calculus, trace

how do we prove $\nabla_Atr(ABA^T)=AB+AB^T$? where B is square, and $\nabla_A$ is the derivative according to every element in A.
I'm getting lost with all the matrix indices... is there a neat way to show this? even an intuitive explanation of why this is true will do for me

Comment: What is $\nabla_A$? Is trace applied to $A$ or to $ABA^T$?

Comment: @StinkingBishop - oops, added some clarifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\p{\partial}$
First note the behavior of the trace function under transposition
$$\eqalign{
f = {\rm Tr}(XBY^T) &= {\rm Tr}\Big((XBY^T)^T\Big) = {\rm Tr}(YB^TX^T) \\
}$$
Next calculate the gradient of the function with respect to $X$ and $Y$
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\p f}{\p X} &= YB^T,\qquad 
\frac{\p f}{\p Y} &= XB \\
}$$
Finally, set $\,X=Y=A\,$ and use the chain rule
$$\eqalign{
\frac{df}{dA}
 &= \left(\frac{\p f}{\p X}\right)\left(\frac{\p X}{\p A}\right)
  + \left(\frac{\p f}{\p Y}\right)\left(\frac{\p Y}{\p A}\right) \\
 &= AB^T + AB \\
}$$

---

The above derivation assumes the following result is already known
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\p \,{\rm Tr}(BY^T)}{\p Y} &= B \\
}$$

Comment: thanks! minor typo - after the "+" it should be $df/dY$. But why is true that $df/dA = df/dX dX/dA + df/dY dY/dA$ ? each part of the sum in the right hand side is an application of the chain rule indeed, but why is the whole equation true?

Comment: Thanks, the typo has been corrected.  The LHS is the total derivative wrt to $A$, while the RHS contains the partial derivatives wrt $A$. I've slightly altered the notation on the LHS to clarify that detail.